# Find a short rebus

Tags: rebus

There is a short rebus as follows. What does the short rebus mean?

> X X -----

(EXPLANATION IS NECESSARY)

Comment: is that a solid line to the right of the XX or is it intended to be 5 dashes??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it's

> Don't cross the line?

Because

> First X acts as a no symbol ("Don't"), the second X is a cross, and the remaining part is a line.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Kiss and ride

Because

> X’s are kisses, and to dash is another way of saying to leave

Answer (score 1):

I guess

> To cross the border. Or
>  To cross the street. Or 
>  To cross the line.

Because

> XX means to cross, ----- means the border, or the street, or the line.